# get Dataobjects from Children - SilverStripe 3.1

Tags: php, silverstripe

I've got a GalleryHolder with Gallery-Pages as children. Each Gallery-Page has a Dataobject(VisualObject) to store the images.

I managed it to get 3 random images from a GalleryPage on it's gallery page and 3 random images from all galleries on the GalleryHolder page.

But what I want are 3 random images for each gallery shown on the GalleryHolder page.

Here's my Code, 
can someone tell me how to do that?

- GalleryHolder: http://sspaste.com/paste/show/525e4b9134940
- Gallery: http://sspaste.com/paste/show/525e4bb25f236
- VisualObject: http://sspaste.com/paste/show/525e4bd3cdfff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the simple solution is to just foreach your children

```
public function getRandomPreviewForAllChildren($numPerGallery=3) {
    $images = ArrayList::create();
    foreach($this->data()->Children() as $gallery) {
        $imagesForGallery = $gallery->GalleryImages()
            ->filter(array('Visibility' => 'true'))
            ->sort('RAND()')
            ->limit($numPerGallery);
        $images->merge($imagesForGallery);
    }
    return $images;
}
```

**// EDIT as reponse to your comments:**

if you want it to be grouped by gallery, I would do it different all together (forget the above code and just do the following):

put this in your Gallery class:

```
// File: Gallery.php
class Gallery extends Page {   
    ...

    public function getRandomPreview($num=3) {
        return $this->GalleryImages()
            ->filter(array('Visibility' => 'true'))
            ->sort('RAND()')
            ->limit($num);
    }
}
```

and then in template of the Parent (the `GalleryHolder`) you just call that function:

```
// File: GalleryHolder.ss
<% loop $Children %>
    <h4>$Title</h4>
    <ul class="random-images-in-this-gallery">
        <% loop $RandomPreview %>
            <li>$Visual</li>
        <% end_loop %>
    </ul>
<% end_loop %>
```

**// EDIT another comment asks for an exaple of a single dataobject:**

if you just want 1 random gallery image, use the following:

```
// File: Gallery.php
class Gallery extends Page {   
    ...

    public function getRandomObject() {
        return $this->GalleryImages()
            ->filter(array('Visibility' => 'true'))
            ->sort('RAND()')
            ->first();
        // or if you want it globaly, not related to this gallery, you would use:
        // return VisualObject::get()->sort('RAND()')->first();
    }
}
```

and then in template you access the method directly:
`$RandomObject.ID` or `$RandomObject.Visual` or any other property
or you can use `<% with %>` to scope it:

```
<% with $RandomObject %>
    $ID<br>
    $Visual
<% end_with %>
```

Comment: Hi Thx, this did the job. But know i've got another problem. How can I get the name of each Gallery?

Comment: do you want the title of the gallery on each image or do you want to group them by gallery to have a sort of headline?

Comment: i want the title of the main gallery. so Gallery 1 is shown with 3 random images and the gallery title, gallery 2 is shown with 3 random images and the gallery title and so on

Comment: so they are grouped by gallery, I see. I'll update the answer with a code example for it later, I am busy right now

Comment: Doh! :D I used the same function before i wrote this question. But i put it into the Gallery_Controller. And than it doesn't work. Thank you

Comment: Would this approach be optimal if you were only trying to get the one random DataObject?

Comment: no. then you would just return a dataobject. I'll update the post