# Silverstripe 3: How to get images from multiple pages for display on another page in a function?

Tags: image, function, silverstripe

I have a PageType - "GalleryPage". There are many of these pages each has a single image called "$ClientLogo". How do I write a function which can call all these ClientLogo images and collate them on a separate page "ClienListPage".

Similar to this [Silverstripe 3: create page control function to get images from grandchild pages and sort all randomly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20531470/silverstripe-3-create-page-control-function-to-get-images-from-grandchild-pages)
but instead of targeting Child pages targeting a specific page type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your Gallery Pages are all children of your Client List Page you can call `loop` on `Children` and retrieve each `ClientLogo`:

**ClientListPage template**

```
<% loop $Children %>
    $ClientLogo
<% end_loop %>
```

If your Gallery Pages are not all children of your Client List Page you will need to create a function in your controller to fetch all your gallery pages to loop through them.

**ClientListPage controller**

```
private static $allowed_actions = array (
    'GalleryPages'
);

function GalleryPages()
{
    $galleryPages = GalleryPage::get();
    return $galleryPages ? $galleryPages : false;
}
```

**ClientListPage template**

```
<% loop $GalleryPages %>
    $ClientLogo
<% end_loop %>
```